# How to set the Image using Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to get the bitmap in my activity , but don't know how to get it from my custom view . Here is my try

Here is my draw method :

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        centerX = getMeasuredWidth()/ 2;
        centerY = getMeasuredHeight()/ 2;
        int radius = Math.min(centerX,centerY);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, outerCircularPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius-1, innerCircularPaint);

    }
```

Here is my Full Code :

```
public class CircleIcon extends View {
    private int centerX,centerY;
    private Paint outerCircularPaint,innerCircularPaint;
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 5;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public CircleIcon(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        outerCircularPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        outerCircularPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        outerCircularPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

        outerCircularPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        outerCircularPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        outerCircularPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.color_black));

        innerCircularPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        innerCircularPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        innerCircularPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        innerCircularPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        centerX = getMeasuredWidth()/ 2;
        centerY = getMeasuredHeight()/ 2;
        int radius = Math.min(centerX,centerY);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, outerCircularPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius-1, innerCircularPaint);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do here, but its probably wrong.  setBitmap makes all future draw commands go to that bitmap.  It should NEVER be called on the canvas from onDraw, and any past commands will not be drawn on that bitmap.  If you're trying to get a view to draw to a bitmap, its probably better to enable its drawing cache and get that.  Failing that, you'd want to create a canvas and set its bitmap int he activity, then pass it to onDraw and the bitmap will have been drawn when the function completes.

Comment: @GabeSechan can you please let me know by editing the above code , how to enable its drawing cache and get that, The following code draw one circle inside the other circle . I actually need Bitmap from this code (i.e canvas) and use this my bitmap in activity